Robot framework custome python library import error
I have created global.robot file consist of variable and import libraries that consist of python file
Total 5 python files I have imported into global.robot  but 3 are giving error of
Unresolved library: libraries/Ansible Runner. Error generating libspec: Importing library 'AnsibleRunner' falled: FileNotFoundError:
I have solve the error inside of python file and also update the virtual environment and also clear cache and restar pycharm

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You have to provide a sample how exactly you import them, and the directory structure. Otherwise - no one should/can imagine it, to help you out.


Unresolved library: libraries/Ansible Runner. Error generating libspec: Importing library 'AnsibleRunner' falled: FileNotFoundError:

See that you library has a space in the filename, and robot removes spaces or undersocres.
You should not use modules with spaces in its filename.
You did not show the Library  import statement in *** Settings ***, but there is probably a mistake in that import. Maybe you should import the Python script, or double check you module or class name.
